# Wrap Scaffold in Row

Tags: flutter

I want to built a split screen for larger devices. One half should be as small as possible but as large as needed and the other half should occupy the rest of the screen.

I figured I'd use a `Row` containing two `Scaffold`s (one wrapped in a `Expanded` widget) like so:

```
Row(children: [
  Scaffold(appBar: MyAppBar1(), body: Container()),
  Expanded(child: Scaffold(appBar: MyAppBar2(), body: Container())),
])
```

However, I get the following error message when wrapping a `Scaffold` inside a `Row`:

> RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

I know that I could just wrap the `Scaffold` inside a SizedBox with a fixed width, but I want the `Scaffold` to automatically take the right size.

Comment: why you are using the Scaffold inside of Row?? Even if two times? It doesnot make sense

Comment: Maybe he needs to have an Appbar or a floating button, so the Scaffold easily provides them.

Comment: @YunusKocatas I need the AppBars (not shown in the code example)

Comment: if you need the app bar you have use the scaffold after MaterialApp not inside of Row Column or Container

Comment: @YunusKocatas it's not mandatory. Scaffold can be nested, although it's not usually necessary. It could be useful especially if you're developing for web or desktop, where you have much more GUI space available than the usual mobile platforms

Answer (score 2):

`Scaffold` itself doesn't have a width constraint, so it will try to occupy as much space as possible (if I'm remembering correctly), and `Row` on its part won't try to constrain it, hence the error.

You have two options:

- wrap the `Scaffold` in another `Expanded`, then use the `flex` argument on both the `Expanded` to give them size relative to each other (i.e., if one has `flex: 1` and the other `flex: 2`, the second one will have twice the size of the first)
- wrap the `Scaffold` in a `ConstrainedBox` and set the `constraints` yourself, which I guess in this case would be the `maxWidth` set on the smaller side

As others pointed out, anyway, if you don't really need another `Scaffold`, you can simply use two `Column` and get a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use two Scaffolds. Use two columns inside one Column in Scaffold. Wrap the second Column with Expanded. This way your first part will take as much space as needed and the second part will take the remaining space.

```
home: Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Replace with Row, if you want to split that way.